# how to use two mysql_fetch_array() arrays in one while loop

Tags: php, database, web

Hi i have two arrays built by using mysql_fetch_array() i want to use them both in one while loop :

```
$username =$_SESSION["username"];
$password =$_SESSION["password"];       
$query1= "SELECT * FROM subs WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password' ";
$res1 = mysql_query($query1);
$row_cnt1 = mysql_num_rows($res1);
if($res1 === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res1);
if($row_cnt1 == 1){
    $sid = $row1["id"];
}else{
    die("there is more than one user with the same username and password");
}


$query2= "SELECT * FROM bookreservations ";
$res2 = mysql_query($query2);
$row_cnt2 = mysql_num_rows($res2);
if($res2 === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}

$row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2) ;

$query= "SELECT * FROM books";
$res = mysql_query($query);
$row_cnt = mysql_num_rows($res);
if($res === FALSE) { 
    die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        if($row2["sid"] == $sid && $row2["bid"] == $row["id"]){
            continue;
        }
        $temp = $row["id"];
        $temp1 = $row["title"];
        echo "Title : ".$temp1."<br><br>";
        $temp1 = $row["authors"];
        echo "Authors : ".$temp1."<br><br>";
        $temp1 = $row["copies"];
        echo "Copies : ".$temp1."<br><br><br><br>";

        echo "<div class=\"re\"><input type=\"radio\" value=\"reserve\" name=\"".$temp ."\">reserve</div> <br><br><br><br><br><br>" ;

    }
```

I want to extract things from row array but i don't want them to have some values from row2 array so I have to use them both in one while loop ,THE SUMMARY row array is ok it jumps to the next row in each loop but row2 array is stuck it doesn't move to the next row what to do ?

Comment: Can't you do it in one query? Something like `SELECT r.*, b.* FROM books b LEFT JOIN r ON r.book_id = b.id GROUP BY b.id`

Comment: I don't know this technique didn't do it before , is there any different ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really understand your task well, I however, would recommend the following edits
My assumption: You are trying to fetch all rows from `$res` for each `$res2`.

Although inefficient technique, but I'll edit your code as below.

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res2) ){


while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){ //Both $row & $row2 will have equal incremented rows.
   }

}//Outer loop
```

Comment: Editing answer.. Checkout